# How to prepare json data from direction service of google map to save in mongo db and plot it again on map

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, google-maps, express

I am using Google Maps Directions service for routes. I want to save the response in JSON format in MongoDB for reuse to plot the route on the map again. How do I have to prepare the JSON data for routes array from the Directions service.

[image: map direction image*emphasized text*]

Answer (score 1):

You can design your mongodb schema like the following. You may want to add some more details.

```
{
    "source": "Ramlal Marg",
    "destination": "Rajaram Kohli Marg",
    "directions" : [
        {
            "type": "Left turn"
            "desc" : "Take a left a turn at XYZ"
        },
        {
            "type": "Right turn"
            "desc" : "Take right turn at ABC"
        },
        {
            "type": "Continue"
            "desc" : "Continue on this road for 4 kms"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: how i want to plot it on map and get the same response.

Comment: You need to check out the google maps documentation for that. Sorry I don't have much experience with that.